# Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Incorrect arguments) in passport [Node.js]

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have used passport for validation and saved the values is resource collection  , and am getting Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Incorrect arguments). But i have used the same name of email and password only

My passport.js in following

```
  var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var User = require('../app/models/db_model');

    module.exports =function(passport){
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user.id);
            //console.log("ser"+user);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
                //console.log("deser"+user);
                done(err, user);
            });
        });

        passport.use('local-userlogin', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) { 

            User.findOne({ 'email' :  email}, function(err, user) {

                console.log(user);
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Invalid Username.'));


                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Invalid Password.'));

                return done(null, user);


            });

        }));
    }
```

Kindly help me in this issue

Comment: Use anonymous functions instead of arrow functions when defining your methods. something like that : `UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(params){...}`

Comment: Am very new to this technology, where i have to use this ?

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error when using Passport with Bcrypt [bcrypt-nodejs].

In my user model I had

```
userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = password => {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(1), null); 
}

userSchema.methods.validPassword = password => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password); 
}
```

Which I then replaced with

```
userSchema.methods.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(5), null);
}

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}
```

And that got rid of the error. 
This seems to imply that `bcrypt-nodejs` does not like arrow functions.

Hope this helped.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I also encountered this error and found out that even @ July 2019 - bcrypt-nodejs still doesn't allow arrow functions. I thought there's something wrong with my async functions but it turns out it's just the arrow function in bcrypt-nodejs